# SwipeRefreshLayout prevents AppBarLayout scrolling down with showing refresh circle after updating support libs to 23.2.0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout, android-support-design

After updating google libs to `23.2.0` faced issue, that was in previous support libs version (as I remember it was `22+` or `23.1.0`).

I have `RecyclerView` in `SwipeRefreshLayout`, which is in `CoordinatorLayout` that have `AppBarLayout` with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

So when I now have `CollapsingToolbarLayout` not fully expanded and try to expand it the swipeRefresh `indicator` appears, instead of expanding `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So seems to be that it's an old-new bug in `23.2.0` version of support library.

When I change my depencies to older version (`23.1.1`) bug dissapears.

Now we should wait for new bug fix for old bug.

There is a list of depencies that you should **not** update to `23.2.0` to avoid this bug:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

---

You can also use [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35643170/3212712) with overriding `SwipeRefreshLayout`

---

Here is link to google bugtracker: [RecyclerView v23.2.0 - doesn't play nicely with SwipeRefreshLayout](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201775)

---

Same question and answer in russian:
[SwipeRefreshLayout не даёт скроллить вниз не раскрытый AppBarLayout показывая вместо этого индикатор загрузки после обновления support до 23.2.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497161/)

---

**UPD 08.04.2016:**

Problem fixed in libs version `23.3.0`.

Comment: Would be good if we could highlight the urgency to Google by starring the relevant issue in the tracker - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201775&q=recyclerview&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: @JamesBritton, thanks for link to bug tracker. I put star on it too)

Comment: Have the same issue in 23.3.0 with `ListView` inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution by fixing nested scrolling in `SwipeRefreshLayout`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36181176/5002337